Could someone explain the difference between 痛そうな顔 & 苦しそうな顔? Is one emotional pain while the other physical pain?
Can someone explain the difference between  "苦しい" and  "痛い"? I know both mean pain but don't know the nuance between the two.

Both can refer to either physical or mental pain.
痛い refers to physical (and usually localized) pain from injuries, headaches, toothaches, gout attacks, etc. 苦しい refers to physical distress from various causes including shortness of breath, high fever, exhaustion, overeating, panic attacks, etc. An 痛そうな顔 and a 苦しそうな顔 typically don't appear that different, but you need to choose the right adjective depending on the assumed cause. For example, it's perfectly normal to describe a marathon runner's face as 苦しそうな顔, but using 痛そうな顔 instead would imply they've injured their foot or something.
These words are also used in contexts related to non-physical pain or suffering:

痛い: Intense heartache, such as after a breakup. Emotional pain when failing to act appropriately in social situations or when a joke falls flat.
苦しい: The distress of financial hardship or being at a disadvantage in sports.
つらい: The suffering caused by mental stress from work or family situations.

